# Formatting JSONP for cross domain webservice in Jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jsonp

i have webservice on external domain, which contain a web-service for sending mails

I want to call cross-domain web-service using jquery ajax, the problem is i could not get the success value, it goes to error even if webservice has successfully executed and mail has been sent

i checked in the firebug (Net Tab), while executing it appends ?callback=[some junk function], and because it does not finds that function, it does not displays proper message.

below is my webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string SendMail()
{
    string returnVal = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("[from]");
        message.To.Add("[to]");
        message.Subject = "TEST";
        message.Body = "TEST MAIL";
        message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("[username]", "[password]");
        client.Send(message);
        returnVal = "[mycallback]({'status':'Success'})";
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex) { returnVal = "[mycallback]({'status':'Fail Reason: " + ex.Message + "'})"; }
    return returnVal;
}
```

and below is my ajax jquery call

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"http://audiomedia.dev.asentechdev1.com/MailSender.asmx/SendMail",
                dataType:"jsonp",
                jsonpCallback: 'mycallback',
                success: function(data){
                    alert(json.Parse(data));
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error: " + data.responseText);
                }   
            });
            function mycallback(data){
                alert("CallBack: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
```

with changing the return value and adding callback i get below reply from server
[image]
but still its going into the error callback, even after successfully sending mail.
can anyone tell me how can format the success message.

Comment: Note that the response I can see in your screenshot is XML not JSON and isn't wrapped inside a method call...

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the response data inside a function with the same name as `SomeJunkFunction`. Eg...

```
SomeJunkFunction() {return {"SomeProperty":"SomeValue"}};
```

As to why this is needed...

The Same origin policy prevents queries cross-domain from returning data. To work around this, you simulate including an external javascript file. The simulated JS file has a function which returns data. The browser assumes the function is static and legitimate so allows it to run.

For the client to know the name of the function provided in "static" js, it passes it in the call eg `SomeJunkFunction` and trusts that the new function you create will be named that way.

See [This page](http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/web-development/javascript/jsonp-example/) for more information and some example code.

**Edit**: To clarify, you don't create the `SomeJunkFunction` on the page itself, it needs to be included in the response from the server. It has no parameters. Your server doesn't return data, it returns a function which, when called, returns data.

Comment: i have updated my question, even after making above changes, its calling error callback only.

Comment: Can you also add to your Q the full details of `e` in your error callback? It sounds like your AJAX call is returning a non-HTTP 200 response

Comment: it was from some site i came across, i changed it to (data) and data.responseText

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error state because you are not returning proper JSONP. In order to complete a cross-domain JSONP request you must return the request wrapped in the callback function generated by jQuery. If jQuery does not receive a response wrapped in this function then the success callback will never be triggered.

Change

```
 return returnVal;
```

to

```
 return "[callback]({status: [returnVal]})";
```

Comment: i have updated my question, even after making above changes, its calling error callback only.